# change permalink structure at template activation?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

is it possible to change the permalink structure at template activation? This is because a default wordpress install has no costum permalink structure selected, I want to define the typical %postname% when the template is activated, I have the code to trigger at the template activation but I do not have the code (and have no ideia how to find it) to change the permalink structure.

Can someone help/tell me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `set_permalink_structure` function should do what you need.  Check out [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31207/how-to-set-permalink-structure-via-functions-php) on the WordPress stack exchange.